# Best way to handle advertising that expands on mouse over

Tags: web, ads

I have recently seen a number of web sites where you want to click a link in content on the page, but as your mouse moves across an advertisement (ad) to get to the link, the ad expands to cover the content link, and I accidently click the ad often leading me someplace as a user where I DID NOT choose to go.

I find this beyond annoying from a user standpoint and feel it reduces site usability.

I do see the value of ads in web sites :) some revenue helps drive the content existance but golly gosh gee I really don't like this.

What is the best way to handle this as a web site developer?

Comment: what do you mean exactly ? how to avoid this when you're an user, or how to place ads in a new website ?

Comment: @Valentin Rocher - really some of both, but mainly as a developer how this situation is/should be handled - or even that information provided to owners of sites that I like to visit otherwise that manifest this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a web site developer you can choose ad proveders who don't do these things. Or manage ads by yourself. Or put a "donate" button.
Autoenlarging ad areas could also violate an ad agreement, where the ad's dimmensions are described. Check the agreement text.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your ad provider has policies in place that do not allow those kind of ads.